# Finding the min and max values in a list of objects, but where the min object must be older than max

Tags: c#, numbers, where-clause

Apologies... I'm not exactly great at coding, but here goes.

Basically I've got a list of a class, that I want to get the min and max for. The part that is tripping me up is that i need the min and max to be in chronological order. Hopefully the drawing helps show what i mean.

[Graph of object with date and value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XTz6.png)

As you can see above, the first value is actually the max, but the minimum is not for another 2 increments.

So i was trying to construct a where statement, but I couldn't figure out how to mix class variable types to query properly... Also how to note that the date of the min must be older than the max, without yet knowing the max (or vice versa).

Obviously the code below doesn't work at all, and the logic on getting the min/max values is flawed, but hopefully it helps make sense of what I'm trying to do...

```
public static MinMax MinandMax(List<ValueHistoric> InputList, int take)
{
    InputList.Reverse();
    var CutList = InputList.Take(take);
    var CutListMax = CutList.Where(a => a.Value == CutList.Max(b => b.Value) && a.Date > CutList.Min.Date);
    var CutListMin = CutList.Where(a => a.Value == CutList.Min(b => b.Value) && a.Date < CutList.Max.Date>);

    //Put Min and Max into variables here

    MinMax results = new MinMax();
    results.Max = last12max;
    results.Min = last12min;
    return results;
}

public class ValueHistoric
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Well, then, the logic should be: find the absolute minimum for all the objects and then search for the maximum in all the objects that follow it chronologically. Please update your post after you try that.

Comment: You want to get the min first.  Then find two max values.  One earlier than the min and one later than the min.

Answer (score 0):

I would first determine the min date `OrderBy` to get the lowest value first

```
var min = CutList.OrderBy(x => x.Value).First();
```

afterwards I would determine the max date - which has to be `> min.Date` 
, `OrderByDesc` to get the highest value first

```
var max = CutList.OrderByDesc(x => x.Value).First(a => a.Date > min.Date);
```

**Update**.. You have to order by the `Value`, not the `Date`

Comment: See now i just feel like an idiot. I was thinking about if there was no max after a minimum (i.e. downward trend etc) but error handling will deal with that... ha thanks!

Comment: In that case use `FirstOrDefault` to return `null` if there is no more valid value to expect

Answer (score 0):

With LINQ, the `Aggregate` method allows you to progressively go through your list and aggregate it by a custom rule in a single pass. Your rule would look like this:

```
(double?, double?) AggregateMinMax((double? Min, double? Max) current,
    double next)
{
    if ((current.Min == null) || (current.Min.Value > next)) {
        return (next, null);
    }
    else if ((current.Max == null) || (next > current.Max.Value)) {
        return (current.Min, next);
    }
    else {
        return current;
    }
}

(double? min, double? max) = CutList.OrderBy(value => value.Date).Select(value => value.Value)
    .Aggregate(((double?)null, (double?)null), AggregateMinMax);
```

You know that you have a result when both `min` and `max` have a value (ie. are not `null`).